# J2ME text field to double

Tags: java, string, java-me, mobile

Is there a way to convert the string from a text field to a double in j2me? And what is the name of the string that comes out of the text field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Double.parseDouble(String) method for converting string to double:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble("22.4");
```

To get text of TextField you can use TextField.getString() method;

```
String text = TextField.getString();
```

So:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(TextField.getString());
```

Comment: `valueOf()` returns a Double object. In Java 5+ that can be auto-unboxed to a `double`. In J2ME this autoboxing doesn't work, so your second line of code won't compile (even in Java 5+ it does unnecessary work and `parseDouble()` should be prefered, when a `double` is needed).

Answer (score 1):

Make a note that floats are only supported on phones that conform to CLDC 1.1, if the phone you are targetting is CLDC 1.0 you will need to use fixed point

Comment: Luckily enough CLDC 1.0 is ancient and mostly gone. CLDC 1.1 isn't the most powerful either, but at least it's got the basics.

Comment: true, about 9% of the market according to getjar
http://stats.getjar.com/statistics/world/gJavaCLDCVer/j2me_cldc_1_0

just worth being aware of!

Answer (score -1):

you can do this as well

```
String s = txtField.getText();

double number1 = Double.parseDouble(s);
```

Comment: there's no `getText()` in [j2me TextField API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/TextField.html)